# How can I verify the energy conservation of a finite difference scheme for Navier--Stokes equations in 2D?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

How can I verify the energy conservation of a  finite difference scheme for Navier--Stokes equations in 2D? I think that the answer with any finite difference scheme is enough to understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about plotting the energy as a function of time?

Comment: I'm refering, how to calculate from the numerical scheme, not the numerical solution

Comment: First, you need a definition of energy: Are you using the physical energy $E$ which defines the third conserved quantity, or are you referring to the "numerical" energy $0.5\sum_i \Vert \boldsymbol{u}_i \Vert_2 ^2$ ?